# How do I append a command to compiler/linker/archive commands

Tags: cmake, ninja

I want to pipe stdout from my compiler commands to a utility which colors warnings, errors, etc. in the command console

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> -c -MD -MF=<OBJECT>.d <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> <SOURCE> -o <OBJECT> | color.exe")
```

However, ninja doesn't seem to recognise the pipe (`|`) notation. Maybe I could prepend `cmd /c` to the compiler call command using `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE`, but I'd rather a platform independent solution.

Is there a rule for piping command outputs? (such as `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE`, but which appends to the compiler commands rather than prepending?)

---

I originally thought about simply piping the output of the `.bat` script which launches CMake, but the color utility path is defined in the CMake toolchain file, as it included as part of one compiler vendor's package.

[update]:
The following CMake commands solves my initial problem by allowing me to pipe the output of a compile command to another program:

```
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "cmd /c") 
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "${CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT} 2>&1 | ${GCOLOR} -f")
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a script to do that and set it as the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` options during configuration (e.g. passing it as an argument to CMake with a `-D` option)?

Comment: I tried adding  `cmd /c` as I was considering when I wrote the question (I think this should basically function the same as your suggestion). The resulting ninja command, `cmd /c <compiler> <options> 2>&1 | <color util>` colours the build output perfectly when I copy-paste and run manually, but it is left uncoloured when run through ninja.

Could it be that `stdout` is grabbed or redirected by ninja, perhaps?

Comment: in your question you mention that you thought of doing that in a script that invokes CMake. I'm suggesting bundling the compiler call in a script and pass-through whatever arguments are provided, and then use that as a `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. I believe the generator rules will just have calls to that script.

Comment: sorry for the confusion @compor.  now the compiler call (as called by ninja) is prepended by `cmd /c`, which should allow shell interpretation (as recommended by the [ninja manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#ref_rule_command)

Comment: According to the [code](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/ca041d88f4d610332aa48c801342edfafb622ccb/src/build.cc) (line 172), Ninja removes all ansi escape codes when not writing to a smart terminal.  This is perhaps the reason I see no colorization when running through Ninja.  I can't find out how smart terminal is determined though.